# Why did React remove the raf implementation?

Tags: reactjs

see https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/17252

What are the disadvantages of rAF compared to messageLoop?

Answer (score 0):

Short: for better performance

Long: [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16214), that actually adds message loop implementation, should answer your question :)